# switch unexpected token in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am finding an unexpected token in the following code.

```
        switch ( hobby ) {
            case =" painting ":
                message = "Van Gogh was good at that.";
                    break;
            case =" drawing ":
                message = "Hey! Van Gogh did that too.";
                    break;
            case =" playing guitar ":
                message = "Bob Dylan played guitar.";
                    break;
            case =" sleeping in ":
                message = "My favorite hobby in the winter.";
                    break;

            default
        }
```

Does anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: In the code before the switch I have var hobby = prompt("What do you like to do? Painting, drawing, playing guitar, or sleeping in.");

Comment: The ending default line is actually not in the my current code.

Comment: It's not what you're missing, it's what you're adding ;) In general, you'll want to have a `default` handler, unless it *truly* doesn't matter--even then, having an empty one with a comment to that effect can be helpful for future code readers.

Comment: Just a note, I often get this error when I forget to add a `:` after one of the keywords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is off.  Remove the `=` after `case`s.  Also, you'll need to put a `:` after `default`.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) for more about `switch` statements.

Comment: Also, you probably want to remove the spaces from your case operands (i.e., change `" painting "` to `"painting"`), since users are unlikely to put spaces before and after their answer.  (I am adding this as a comment instead of part of my answer because it doesn't directly correlate with your question.)

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of function semantics to avoid having to `break` out of each `case`:

```
var message = (function(){
  switch (hobby) {
    case 'painting':        return 'Van Gogh was good at that.'
    case 'drawing':         return 'Hey! Van Gogh did that too.'
    case 'playing guitar':  return 'Bob Dylan played guitar.'
    case 'sleeping in':     return 'My favorite hobby in the winter.'
  }
}())
```

The best way to express this logic, though, is probably something like the following:

```
var messages = {
  'painting':       'Van Gogh was good at that.',
  'drawing':        'Hey! Van Gogh did that too.',
  'playing guitar': 'Bob Dylan played guitar.',
  'sleeping in':    'My favorite hobby in the winter.'
}
var message = messages[hobby]
```

Comment: And a `default: return '';` case.